# Get package by variable

Tags: r, namespaces, environment

Using a character variable `pkg_var` containing a package name: How can I get an internal object of that package?

I am looking for something like `getPackage(x = pkg_var):::internal_object`

`mypackage:::internal_object` works of course, but is hard-coded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getFromNamespace`:

```
getFromNamespace("cor.test.default", "stats")
#returns the function
```